# How should be Monitor Tomcat from local machine

Tags: tomcat, monitoring

Hi i am running Tomcat server in production server(A Ubuntu machine), but i have checked after 3-4 days when i am browse application through URL its not responding when i cheked server through login on production server by following command

```
ps -ef|grep tomcat
```

It showing `PID` it mean Tomcat is running but when i am trying to access application it is not available.
Then i have to restart the server again then everything work fine. What would be cause of this issue and what all thing i have to check i checked log file of Tomcat no any blunder i found on that .

Can any one tell me what can be reason of this issue and how can we resolve this? Also any open source  tool to  Monitor Tomcat from local machine. So it would send mail if any issue arise on Tomcat server

Answer (score 1):

Monit is an open source command line tool that can use used to monitor any process including tomcat.

http://mmonit.com/monit/

A blog explaining how to set it up to monitor (and auto restart) tomcat:

http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2011/01/27/setting-up-monit-with-tomcat/

Comment: Also as blog mention they install tomcat in Ubuntu machine while i have not installed tomcat I just downloaded it from Apache site then i am using it

Comment: You need to configure monit so that it knows what to monitor, and what to do when something stops working (ie send an email, or restart it etc)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you have tomcat running as a process on your Ubuntu box then you can install monit on the same box to monitor it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472725/monitoring-apache-tomcat-applications-in-production-environment?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the logs and pull a stack trace to see, what's going on inside the JVM. There are several tools like Nagios or Zabbix to perform monitoring/alerting for different services (also HTTP-based).

Comment: I think these tools are not open source